# Treat local files as remote / process files by webserver instead of reading them directly

Tags: php, file

I'm writing a really simple app in PHP. And I've got a PHP script creating dynamically an XML file. That XML file needs to be accessed both directly by the user's browser, and by another PHP script.

If it were a complex app, I'd have some kind of framework to do this kind of dual access for me.

But as the app is really simple, I don't want to use any framework or MVC architecture.

What I'd preferably want to do is to be able to call `file_get_contents('script.php')` and let the local file `script.php` be processed by the webserver instead of reading it locally.

I see several ways to do it, but I don't like any of them:

- calling something like `file_get_contents($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. ... . '/script.php')` - this seems to be overly complex and error-prone
- getting the file with curl - not all hostings have curl enabled
- doing it using `ob_start()` and the friend functions - that's ugly
- extracting the XML-generating code to a string-returning function - as the XML file grows large, the lack of streamed processing could be a bottle-neck

Do you have any other/nicer ideas?

Comment: 4th seems very nice, optimize later if you ever find yourself in the situation of it being a bottleneck (premature optimalization etc..). It has the _same_ drawbacks as the rest of them (having the whole XML in memory), neither `curl`, `file_get_contents`, of `ob_start` work differently. If you'd talk about `readfile`, yes, then maybe less memory overhead.

Comment: @Wrikken : That's currently how I'm implementing it :)